# Looping over dynamic list that it's index will change

Tags: python

So i have a problem with loops.
If i have two lists

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

I will loop through them and delete elements and append it to the other list
so my list would be

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [6]
```

OR list could be strings <

Now how when i'm loop like:

```py
for i in range(len(list2))
```

I know my program will pop out with `IndexError: list index out of range`
is there any way to loop effeciently without getting out of the both list (like checking both)
*without using any libraries* like itertools etc..

Example code:

```py
for i in range(len(list1)):
  if(list1[i] > list2[i]):
      list1.append(list2[i])
      del list2[i]
  else:
      list2.append(list1[i])
      del list1[i]
```

Comment: What's the specific use case ? can you please explain bit more ?  why only p6 remains in your list 2 why not p5 or p4 ?

Comment: Use shallow copy for iteration `list2[:]` or `list2.copy()`

Comment: This is unclear, could share more code ?

Comment: @BoseongChoi that's the static one.

Comment: @Juhil Somaiya If i have a program that give elements to another list that's the case and keeps what's not taken yet

Comment: @azro What's unclear? please be specific. It's basic idea, list1 takes few elements from list2 depends on a condition. and loop breaks if len(list1) > 4

Comment: @YousefGH please provide minimal working example. 
What's the condition for taking elements from list2 to list1 and which to keep

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya The list will be randomly generated so that i only condition would be if (len(list1) > 4 or len(list2) > 4)

Comment: @azro, are you able to understand what op is asking ?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya I've added a code example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) for list of mutables (like `list`)

Use only [:] for list of immutables (like `int`)

**EDIT**

```py
list1 = ['p', 'p2', 'p3']
list2 = ['p4', 'p5', 'p6']

for item in list2[:]:
    if item != 'p6':
        list1.append(item)
        list2 = list2[1:]
```

BTW, if you only want to concat these two lists, you can simply run `list1.extend(list2)`

**EDIT 2**
What in your code is not the question you asked. Just add some if statement:

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if len(list1) > i and len(list2) > i:
        if list1[i] > list2[i]:
            list1.append(list2[i])
            del list2[i]
        else:
            list2.append(list1[i])
            del list1[i]
    else:
        # print('out of range. skipping')  # or raise exception or break
        continue
# [2]
# [4, 5, 6, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Perfect example, i've changed the code on the question to be more clear. Could you check it please?

Comment: @YousefGH what's the purpose of your code? I didn't get it...

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on how you implement this, for example:

```py
list1 = ['p', 'p2', 'p3']
list2 = ['p4', 'p5', 'p6']

list2 = list2[::-1]
for _ in range(len(list2)):

    list1.append(list2[-1])
    list2.pop()

list2
[]
list1
['p', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6']
```

will not yield an error.

Comment: What if there's a case? like the one i've provided on the question. where list2 takes from list1

Comment: The example code you added is always entering the `else` part of the loop, i.e. adding elements of `list1` to `list2`. I am not sure to understand your logic of deleting and adding elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
for element in list2:
    list1.append(element)
    list2.remove(element)
```

Comment: what if it's element of list1 going to list2?